# How to push to localhost:500 registry:2 - connect: connection refused

Tags: docker-buildkit, buildx

Created local registry:

```
reg_name='kind-registry'
reg_port='5000'
running="$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' "${reg_name}" 2>/dev/null || true)"
if [ "${running}" != 'true' ]; then
  docker run \
    -d --restart=always -p "127.0.0.1:${reg_port}:5000" --name "${reg_name}" \
    registry:2
fi
```

Created a builder:

```
docker buildx create --name my-builder --platform linux/arm64

docker buildx build --builder my-builder --tag localhost:5000/micro --platform linux/arm64 --push -f ./docker/Dockerfile .
```

Error:

```
 > exporting to image:
------
error: failed to solve: failed to do request: Head "http://localhost:5000/v2/micro/m1/blobs/sha256:cb74f5ebe9cfa5414583bf566983f0ac366f4f6d0b69df2bad27005295378933": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Forlorn hope but - did you get any further with that?

Comment: Hi Tim, Unfortunately not - it was to much of a hassel, so moved back to dockerHub. Let me know it you find a solution ;-)

Comment: I was in a similar situation running `buildctl` directly on the Docker host. Using `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` fixed it for me.